# calling Action with BeginInvoke from external thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, action

```
// This method never gets called
public void DoSomethingWithByte(byte b) 
{
    Writeline(b);
}

class Test<T>
{
    public Test(Action<T> act, T data)
    {

        Dispatcher.Current.BeginInvoke(act, data);
    }
}

void TestAll()
{
   new Test<Byte>(DoSomethingWithByte, 6);
}
```

this does not work, why?

It compiles, gets to the line, but does not call the method

Why is this happening?

Comment: `act` isn't initialized. If it is a field, it will be `null` and explains the behavior you are seeing. If it is a local variable your code will not compile, so please show your real code.

Comment: Does act have a value assigned to it somewhere?. From your exact example act looks null

Comment: I edited the question, now it is clear

Answer (score 1):

Act doesn't have a method to call, it is null.

```
Action<byte> act = ((byte b) DoSomethingwithByte(b));
```

Then have your method.

```
public void DoSomethingWithByte(byte b) {}
```

Comment: @ГошУ Don't put "..." as if I was supposed to know that your code was there. In the future, post **all** of your code and you might get a helpful answer.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean this, more like 'stupid me'. Now the problem is that act is Action<T> and the argument is not passed correctly in my opinion. Why is that?